# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features' Google colab

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

Google colab

This is code for Encoding categorical data

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 2]) #For month
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 3]) #For weekday
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [2])#dummy variable for month
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [13])#dummy variable for week
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]
```

I am getting this error for this and I am facing following errors here. I have already update all library from anaconda prompt. But can't findout the solution of the problem.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-faafd78b922d> in <module>()
      4 labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
      5 X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 3]) #For weekday
----> 6 onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [2])#dummy variable for month
      7 X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
      8 X = X[:, 1:]

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'
```

Comment: Replace `categorical_features`  with `categories` in the `OneHotEncode` constructor, then it should work.

Comment: use sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer and to it pass OneHotEncoder as the required argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df
```

[image: data frame]

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()
df.town=le.fit_transform(df.town)
df
```

[image: data frame]

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ohe=ColumnTransformer([('OHE',OneHotEncoder(),['town'])],remainder='passthrough')
x=ohe.fit_transform(df.drop('price',axis='columns'))
x=x[:,1:]#dropping the first column to avoid dummy variable trap
x
```

[image: x_numpy.array]

```
y
```

[image: y_numpy array]

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)
reg.predict([[1,0,3600]])
```

[image: predicted values by LinearRegression]

For more details regarding [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)  .